# Maximum independent sets in a tree

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Does every maximum independent set in a tree contain a leaf?

Note that the question is not about whether every leaf is present in some maximum independent set (which is indeed the case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's a very interesting question.
I don't understand why anyone would vote down.

Here's the solution I propose.

Let $T$ be a tree with $n$ vertices and let $S$ be a maximum independent set of $T$.
Since the tree is a bipartite graph, then a maximum independent set of $T$ contains at least half of all vertices of $T$, that is $|S|\geq n/2$.

Suppose that $S$ does not contain any leaves.
It follows that
$$
\sum\limits_{x\in S}\operatorname{deg}(x)\geq 2|S|\tag1.
$$
On the other hand, since $S$ is an independent set we have
$$
\sum\limits_{x\in S}\operatorname{deg}(x)\leq|E(T)|=n-1<n\tag2.
$$

It follows from inequalities $(1)$ and $(2)$ that $|S|<n/2$. Contradiction.

**PS.** Thanks to Mike Earnest for an excellent proof of the inequality $(2)$.

Comment: Here's a more conceptual way to prove $(2)$. Imagine placing, for each $x\in S$, a marker on all edges adjacent to $x$. You place $\sum_{x\in S}\text{deg }x$ markers. Since $S$ is independent, no edge gets two markers, so the number of markers is at most the number of edges of $T$, which is $n-1$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.